# Spring MVC: How to correctly create the entity for following JSON response

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am having trouble correctly creating a model / entity for a Spring MVC `RestTemplate.exchange` request which will correspond to this JSON response:

```
{
    "resourceLookup": [
        {
            "version": 0,
            "permissionMask": 1,
            "creationDate": "2017-08-16T12:52:30",
            "updateDate": "2017-08-16T12:52:30",
            "label": "",
            "description": "",
            "uri": "",
            "resourceType": ""
        },
        {
            "version": 5,
            "permissionMask": 1,
            "creationDate": "2017-08-16T11:34:04",
            "updateDate": "2017-08-17T08:27:02",
            "label": "",
            "description": "",
            "uri": "",
            "resourceType": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I've created the following models:

Report class (getters/setters omitted):

```
public class Report implements Serializable {
    private Long version;
    private String permissionMask;
    private Date creationDate;
    private Date updateDate;
    private String label;
    private String description;
    private String url;
    private String resourceType;

    public Report() {
    }
```

ResourceLookup class:

```
public class ResourceLookup implements Serializable {
    List<Report> reports;

    public ResourceLookup() {
    }

    public List<Report> getReports() {
        return reports;
    }

    public void setReports(List<Report> reports) {
        this.reports = reports;
    }
}
```

In the end the response is `reports=null`. If I return a `String` with this code everything is fine:

```
restTemplate.exchange(serverUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class).getBody();
```

I need to correctly map it to the models so that I can return a correctly formatted JSON to my other API's.

Comment: side note, the `permissionMask` is defined as String but in JSON it looks line a number.

Comment: @tima thanks. Well noted and fixed.

Comment: Why an array of `Report` should be named `resourceLookup` instead of `reports`? That's what you have in your JSON output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
public class ResourceLookup implements Serializable {
    List<Report> resourceLookup;

    public ResourceLookup() {
    }

    public List<Report> getResourceLookup() {
        return resourceLookup;
    }

    public void setResourceLookup(List<Report> resourceLookup) {
        this.resourceLookup = resourceLookup;
    }
}
```